# Further cleanup after closing a socket channel

Tags: java, nio, socketchannel

Is there need to do further cleanup after closing a socket channel if the channel was used with a selector and the selector is still being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Closing the channel cancels the selection key. It will be removed from the key set on the next `select()`.

However, when the current `select()` returns, it is possible for a cancelled key to be in the selected-keys set, which you can detect via `SelectionKey.isValid()`, as seen in any decent NIO select loop example.